# Pseudoeffective but anti-nef divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Does anyone has a nontrivial example of Cartier divisor $D$ on a projective variety $X$, such that $D$ is pseudoeffective but $-D$ is nef?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nef divisor is also pseudo-effective so if $D$ is pseudo-effective and $-D$ is nef, then both $D$ and $-D$ are pseudo-effective and hence $D\equiv 0$ (numerically trivial). I assume this is not considered a non-trivial example.

Comment: Aren't you implicitly killing torsion of Picard?

Comment: Antoine, I think that Sándor is talking about numerical equivalence classes of (rational, or real Cartier) divisors: there, there is no torsion! The concept itself of pseudoeffective (Cartier) divisor is usually defined for $\mathbb Q$-numerical equivalence classes, since you have to take limits...

Comment: What *diverietti* said. (Thanks Simone!)

Comment: I guess one could say alternatively that being pseudo-effective is defined up to torsion, so then any torsion divisor satisfies the requirement. 

Comment: Hehe! You're welcome, I was afraid you weren't able to answer all alone... :)

Comment: I basically agree with both of you! But a divisor is a divisor, a $\mathbf Q$-divisor is something else, hence my confusion.
Moreover, some (more than respectable) mathematicians even define pseudo-effectivity for line bundles, so...

Comment: @ACL: *diverietti* was not talking about $\mathbb Q$-divisors but $\mathbb Q$-numerical equivalence. His point was that although one says "pseudo-effective divisor" and even "pseudo-effective line bundle", the definition implies that these notions make sense for the ($\mathbb Q$-numerical) divisor **classes**, not the divisors themselves.  The sensible resolution that allows both usage is to say that a divisor is pseudo-effective if its $\mathbb Q$-numerical equivalence class is pseudo-effective. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd): In fact, this is the way Demailly defines it: (On a projective variety) $\mathscr L$ is pseudo-effective if $c_1(\mathbb L)$ is in the closure of the effective cone in $H^2(X,\mathbb R)$. So he mods out by torsion as well. So, I guess you are right (as I already said in a comment above) that torsion divisors would give examples to the question, but in some sense those are trivial examples and hence do not truly answer the actual question. Cheers!

Comment: @ACL: I think all this is just a matter of reflexes... As you and also Sándor said, torsion non-trivial classes give of course examples of pseudoeffective "anti-nef" divisors. My personal point of view (more "curvature", as you guess) makes me instinctively consider "zero" a line bundle endowed with a flat metric, as long as "positivity" concepts like pseudoeffective or nef are concerned. Cheers!

Comment: I should have made my question clearer: pseudo-effectiveness here is defined for a $\mathbb{Q}$-numerical equivalence class in $\mathbb{Q}$-Neron Severi Space. By trivial, I mean $D=0$. 

But I don't see why the pseudo-effective cone of $X$ cannot contain a line, as indicated in S$\acute{a}$ndor's argument?

Answer (score 3):

As Sándor said, this implies that $D$ must be zero (numerically).  However, it can happen that $D$ is pseudo-effective while at the same time $-D$ is relatively nef (or even relatively ample) with respect to some map.  For example, if you blow up a point on $\mathbb{P}^2$, then the exceptional divisor is effective, but $-E$ is relatively ample.

Comment: Or take any effective divisor relative to the identity map.